# Using charts in iPhone applications

Tags: ios, charts

I want to add charts feature in my application..

I have gone through with various links in OLD posts. Most of the links are not working.

And I am unable to checkout core plot API with below link
[core plot API](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/checkout).

Getting error:

> Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed)

So can any one suggest OR provide link for any latest libraries or API which I can use?

Comment: What kind of charts do you need? I also made an app with a piechart and barchart. The thing about coreplot is that it is quite heavy. So i ended coding my own charts. Just a tip..

Comment: @TompaLompa ok thanks..can you share link for paiechart and barchart or sample code..

Comment: It too much code to paste here...

Comment: I was just pointing out a different approach to your problem. Probably more work, but the upside would be that your app weighs less AND you can implement your design instead of coreplot's.

Comment: you can also check http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1 and part 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download latest Core Plot chart library release from this link:

https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=CorePlot_1.1.zip&can=2&q=

You will get core clot library and an example using the above downloaded link.

Below is the link for instructions to integrate this in your application:

https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: You can see the example. It is showing the PIE and Bar chart both.